# Fedora 26 doesn't show all space

Tags: fedora

I've installed Fedora as my only OS with all default settings. When I chose the drive in the installation I clicked delete all and then reclaimed (I've only 1 drive with ~250 GB).

It said 50 GB root 179 GB home 7.7 GB swap.

But after the installation I get this:

[image]

Where is my remaining space?

The output of `df -Th`, as I was asked in the comments:

```
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G   45M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G  2.2M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root ext4       49G  5.1G   42G  11% /
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.9G  144K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2               ext4      976M  111M  799M  13% /boot
/dev/sda1               vfat      200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora-home ext4      176G  331M  167G   1% /home
tmpfs                   tmpfs     783M   20K  783M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                   tmpfs     783M   12M  772M   2% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `df -Th`

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson added to the question

Comment: I don't see a problem here. `/` comes up as 49 GB and `/home` as 176 GB...

Comment: Can you post the output of the `df` command as text for better accessibility, screen readers for example?

Comment: I've added. Could you please answer my question in the marked answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the `df -Th` output, your `/home/` is **176GB**. What you see as the size of your computer is your **root** partition.

Comment: So how can I see how much free space I have in home?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy the "Avail" column in your output is the amount of space available on each mount point, so in this case you have `167G` free

Comment: @EricRenouf I mean is there more user friendly way that running this command?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy if you just don't want all the other lines, you can run `df -Th /home` and get only that line and the header

Comment: I find it handy to use `alias df='/usr/bin/df -lh -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs'` so that only real local filesystems are shown.